# Sum up String Values within Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to sum up product prices within an array with a GTM custom JS. The array elements are variable. My data source variable looks like this:

```
dl_products_checkout = [ { name: 'Sports Gel SPF 20', id: '1125200001', price: '23.9', brand: 'ultrasun', quantity: 1 }, { name: 'Almost Powder Makeup SPF 15 9 g Neutral', id: '1081040004', price: '25.9', brand: 'Clinique', quantity: 1 } ]
```

Unfortunately I get NaN as the return. Here is my solution so far:

```
function() {
  var items = {{dl_products_checkout}};
  var ids = [];
  var totalValue = 0;
  var i, len;
  for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    totalValue += parseInt(items[i].price);
  }
  return ids.push(totalValue);
}
```

It'd be great if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks a lot!

Best regards, 
Anton

Comment: are you sure, you want integers to add? and return only the length of the array, instead of the array itself? but i get no `NaN`, if `{{ ... }}` is right.

Comment: It looks like you are returning an array rather than a numeric value which would explain the NaN result...

Comment: if you do a  `parseInt('23.9')` you will get `23` instead of `23.9`.
You need a `parseFloat`.

Answer (score 1):

For one, I think you return the wrong value...

Try this:

```
/***
    We create a function, we might want to use it more then once.
***/
function CalculateTotal( items ) {
    // First we check if we have something to work with.
    if ( items.length < 1 || items === undefined ) {
        return null;

    } else { // We can do stuff
        var total_value = 0; // we need something to store the total value in.

        for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i ++ ) { // Let's go through the list.
            total_value += items[i].price; // add the price to total
            console.log( "total_value = " + total_value ); // check total value
            console.log( items[i].name + " = " + items[i].price ); // check item price
        }
        // now we are all done
        return total_value;
    }
```

And use like:

```
var total = CalculateTotal( dl_products_checkout );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your quick response! I just figured out a solution which works for me:

```
function() {
  var items = {{dl_products_checkout}};
  var itemsValue = [];
  var sumValue = 0;
  var i, len;
  for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    itemsValue.push(items[i].price);
        for (i = 0; i < itemsValue.length; i++){
          sumValue = sumValue + parseFloat(itemsValue[i])
        }
  }
  return sumValue;
}
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi Flummox, since I'm quite new in stackoverflow I'm not very familiar with the processes here. Would you mind telling me how I can spend credits? Thanks

Comment: Welkome! the "credits" here are upvotes. I highly recommend upvoting things that help, even if only halfway: they don't cost you a dime, and let's the receiver know you appreciated their input / work. 

Under your name you see your reputation, that is gained by upvotes, or reduced by downvotes. That combined with the badges gives you an idea (but not completely) about the user and their abilities.